# video file cant play with Action_View uri got from Document file on removeable Storage

Tags: android, actionview, documentfile

I could just get my files on removable storage by action_open_document tree and it gives me a document file. I can not open this file with Action_view.
The URI from document file did work!
I can open image file with action view .

```
String uri=DocumentFile.getUri.toString;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uri);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(uri), "video/mp4");
activity.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other apps do not have access to that content. Add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent` to pass along your own read access to the third-party app.